# magento order status change

Tags: magento, status

In magento2 back end  when I submit shipment the order status will changes from processing to complete but I can't  find  where the code execute this

can any one tell me where I can find the code?

I use magento2.4.3-p1

I found the code in "vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php" when execute this method   “_saveShipment” the status will changel,but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

It's in [\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Handler/State.php) which is called whenever the Order is saved.

Answer (score 0):

In "Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order" there is a function Save(). Within the function you can retrieve and modify value of 'status' of Order.
Writing a plugin is preferable.

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order">
    <plugin name="after_plugin_order_state" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginName"/>
</type>
```

PluginName.php

```
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject,
     $result,$object
){
    $setCustomStatus = $object->setData('status','Complete');
    return $result
 }
```